# Insert values from an existing column when using mutate and case_when

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to add a `z` column to the `ds` dataframe with the corresponding "y" value, when the condition in the x column is met.

```
library(tidyverse)
ds <- tibble(x = 1:5,y = 6:10)

ds%>%
  mutate(
    z = case_when(
      x == 3 ~ y,
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
  )
```

I want the corresponding value in the y column to be in the `z` column, but how do I refer to the y column in the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
ds%>%
  mutate(
    z = case_when(
      x == 3 ~ y,
      TRUE ~ NA_integer_
    )
  )
# A tibble: 5 x 3
      x     y     z
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     6    NA
2     2     7    NA
3     3     8     8
4     4     9    NA
5     5    10    NA
```